# Can't add Intervention/Image to the alias array in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've added to `aliases` array this entry:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

This causes my Laravel app to reach the php time limit of 30 sec (or memory limit in case I increase the time limit to 120 sec) even without actual useage of this class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, if you comment out that line does everything load normally again?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, everything works fine. I can even use `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` class specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, it's hard to find out what might went wrong, but here are steps that worked for me:

```
$ cd my-laravel-app
$ composer require intervention/image
```

Edit `config/app.php` and add:

- `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` to the end of `$providers`
- `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class` to the end of `$aliases`

I also recommend you to check your system requirements at [image.intervention.io](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation).

Comment: I've did exactly this, and get this error. I have all requirements except imagick, but I don't need it. `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` class works well. What does not work is alias in `config/app.php` file. As long as it commented out, everything works fine.